# Kubernetes qBitTorrentWebUI showing only on path '/'

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am trying to host a qBitTorrent server with Kubernetes. I have composed a YAML for the `https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/qbittorrent` docker container.

The problem is that it is accessible only from path /. As soon as I move it to /torrent it does not find it anymore: 404 Not Found.

### Steps to replicate:

- apply following yamls
- `helm install nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx`
- go to `service_ip:8080`, settings, WebUI, uncheck "Enable Host header validation"
- go to `localhost:nginx_port/torrent`

### Result:

- page not loading

### Expected Result:

- qBitTorrent WebUi appears and works

### What I tried:

- adding `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /` to annotations

server.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: torrent-deployment
  labels:
    app: torrent
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      pod-label: torrent-pod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        pod-label: torrent-pod
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: linuxserver
        image: linuxserver/qbittorrent:amd64-latest
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: torrent-service
  labels:
    app: torrent
spec:
  selector:
    pod-label: torrent-pod
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    name: torrent-deployment
```

ingress.yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: torrent-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  labels:
    app: torrent
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /torrent
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: torrent-service
            port:
              number: 8080
```

Comment: I am not sure if it is a good idea to try to serve this site differently than expected because it may not work as expected. In similar situations, we can use a reverse proxy for the WebUI (see: [NGINX Reverse Proxy for Web UI](https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/wiki/NGINX-Reverse-Proxy-for-Web-UI))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @matt_j I have found a workaround. I wrote and YAML for nginx myself and added the configurations from the post mentioned by matt ( https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/wiki/NGINX-Reverse-Proxy-for-Web-UI ) and it worked.

These are the YAMLs I came up with:

server.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
  namespace: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      pod-label: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        pod-label: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:latest
        volumeMounts:
          - name: nginx-conf
            mountPath: /etc/nginx/
      volumes:
        - name: nginx-conf
          configMap:
            name: nginx-conf
            items:
            - key: nginx.conf
              path: nginx.conf
  replicas: 1
# status:
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: nginx
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    pod-label: nginx
  ports:
  - port: 80
    name: nginx
```

config.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-conf
  namespace: nginx
data:
  nginx.conf: |
    user  nginx;
    worker_processes  auto;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
    pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

    http {
            server {
                    server_name 10.152.183.95;
                    listen 80;
                    location /torrent/ {
                            proxy_pass              http://torrent-service.qbittorrent:8080/;
                            #proxy_http_version      1.1;
                            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host        $http_host;
                            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $remote_addr;
                            #proxy_cookie_path      /                       "/; Secure";
                            }
            }
    }

    events {
        worker_connections  1024;
    }
```